# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' while using fancyapps/ui and nextjs during runtime

Tags: next.js, fancybox, fancybox-2, fancybox-3

I'm using **NextJs** and below is my package file details

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fancyapps/ui": "^4.0.27",
    "daisyui": "^2.14.3",
    "gsap": "^3.10.4",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "swiper": "^8.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "eslint": "8.15.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.1.6",
    "postcss": "^8.4.13",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24"
  }
```

This runs well when I run `npm run dev` but when I try to build the code it give error.
Also the Vercel deployment gives error in build time as below

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
 at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
 at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1032:15)
 at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1067:27)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:10)
 at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
 at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
 at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
 at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
 at Object.6833 (/vercel/path0/.next/server/pages/gallery.js:63:41)
 at __webpack_require__ (/vercel/path0/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42) {
 type: 'SyntaxError'
 }
 Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1
```

Can someone please help me find a way out of this?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 2):

Install https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules this package and try loading inside your next-config.js

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')(['@fancyapps/ui']);

const nextConfig = {
     ...yourConfig
};

module.exports = withTM(nextConfig);
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using this package with nextjs and facing this issue, just replace the `esm` with `umd` and it works perfectly without any issue.

The react wrapper snippet for fancybox looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

import { Fancybox as NativeFancybox } from "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.umd";
import "@fancyapps/ui/dist/fancybox.css";

function Fancybox(props) {
  const delegate = props.delegate || "[data-fancybox]";

  useEffect(() => {
    const opts = props.options || {};

    NativeFancybox.bind(delegate, opts);

    return () => {
      NativeFancybox.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return <>{props.children}</>;
}

export default Fancybox;
```